Python Tkinter structured in a Class: Can methods be in an independent file?
I'm setting up a Tkinter GUI in what's becoming a rather long Python class with attributes toward the top and methods toward the bottom. To avoid the need for so much scrolling up and down, it would be convenient to separate the methods into an independent file. But I can't stumble upon the exact syntax to let the two files talk to each other as parts of one class. Snippets that follow are pared severely and edited.
GUI is defined in classExample.py:
# Imports from standard Python modules
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

# Imports from custom app modules
import opus as op

# Graphical User Interface
class WC:

    def __init__(self, root, op):
        
        # Root window
        self.root = root

        # App structure: Notebook tab manager with two tabs
        self.nb = ttk.Notebook(self.root)
        self.tab1 = ttk.Frame(self.nb)
        self.nb.add(self.tab1, text="")
        self.tab2 = ttk.Frame(self.nb)
        self.nb.add(self.tab2, text="")
        self.nb.grid()

        # Tab two, structure: two Frames side by side, form and control
        self.tab2_form = ttk.Frame(self.tab2)
        self.tab2_ctrl = ttk.Frame(self.tab2)
        self.tab2_form.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=30, pady=10)
        self.tab2_ctrl.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=30, pady=10)
        ...

        # Tab two, "form" Frame: widgets
        ...
        self.country_input = tk.StringVar()
        self.country_box = ttk.Combobox(self.tab2_form, values=["Canada", "Mexico", "USA",], textvariable=self.country_input)
        self.country_box.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=("N", "E", "S", "W"), padx=10, pady=5)
        self.country_box.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", op.set_country)
        ...
        self.root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    WC(root, op)
    root.mainloop()


Method is defined in custom module opus.py:
from classExample import WC as wc

# Methods that operate with user data
country = ""
def set_country(self):
    country = wc.country_input.get()



The second way (without self) is correct. Having wc.self.country_input is wrong. As for why the second way doesn't work either, it's not clear from the code you have provided. Most likely the part where you do self.country_box = ... is in the wrong place. To be clear, is self.country_box created inside Class? Or in some other part of the code?

The codes are spread into blocks that hard to link together.  It is better to provide a [mre].  Also avoid calling mainloop() inside __init__().

Note that self.country_input is an instance variable. You need to create an instance of the class and access that instance variable using the instance of the class.

Reply to @steliosbl: As shown in my most recent edit, the combobox widget self.country_box is created inside the class (now named WC), same indentation as self.root.

Reply to @acw1668: Yes, I mean self.country_input to be an instance variable. Doesn't the bottom line but one in classExample.py create the instance, within which the widgets in the class will execute?

function def set_country(self): should be defined inside class WC:. If you want to keep it in separate file then don't import wc to this file but import set_country() to file which creates instance my_wc =  WC(root, opa) and run it as set_country(my_wc) and use self.country_input.get() instead of wc.country_input.get()

@prainbow Yes you have created an instance of WC inside classExample.py, but wc inside opera.py is an alias of the class WC, not the instance created.

@prainbow Note that self in def set_country(self) is a reference to virtual event object actually for your case, so you can use self.widget.get() to get the selected value of the combobox.  Also it is better to rename self to event.

Many thanks, even by trying to implement everyone's comments I haven't solved this. Can't seem to translate the concepts into actual code that works.

Did you try my last suggestion? Change country = wc.country_input.get() to country = self.widget.get() inside set_country() function in opus.py.

@acw1668: Yes, I commented out the mainloop() call in classExample.py (as you suggested May 29), and substituted your get() call for mine. Result: "ImportError: cannot import name 'set_country' from partially initialized module 'opus' (most likely due to a circular import)".

If you have used self.widget.get() inside set_country(), then you don't need the import line from classExample import WC as wc.

Code in opus.py that worked with classExample.py above:
# Methods that operate with user data
country = ""
def set_country(self):
    country = self.widget.get()
    print(f"Country: {country}")


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
